# Under what conditions on the field k will all symmetric matrices be diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

It's a theorem that if $A$ is an $n \times n$ symmetric matrix ($A = A^{T}$) with real entries, then $A$ is diagonalizable. The proof goes like this: $A$ has a complex eigenvalue, since $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed. $A = A^{T}$ means that eigenvalue is real. Then, if $v$ is the corresponding eigenvector, it is easy to show that $A$ preserves $v^{\perp}$, and then you can use induction on dimension.

So, if you replace $\mathbb{R}$ with a field $k$, when does this continue to hold? If $k = \bar{k}$ ($k$ algebraically closed) then this is true, and if $k[\sqrt{-1}]$ is algebraically closed you can easily modify the above argument. Are there any other cases when this would be true?

Comment: You can diagonalize matrix with symmetric elementary operations, so my guess is that you can to it in any field.

Comment: Well, [[1, 1],[1, 0]] has the golden ratio as an eigenvalue, so your field needs to have sqrt(5). Meaning you can't do it over the rational numbers.

Comment: And more generally you can show that all 2x2 symmetric matrices are diagonalizable if and only if the sum of perfect squares is always a perfect square.

Comment: You need to be a bit careful in positive characteristic, for example [[0,1],[1,0]] is not diagonalizable in characteristic 2.